# Конкатенация span в Android

Tags: java, android, span

Пробую сделать, что бы в тексте, выводимом в TextView, было "Необходимо ХХХ руб." Но ХХХ должно быть красным цветом.

Пробую так:

```
public void onButtonClick (View v) {
        TextView Total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result); 

        float Sum = (Tank-FuelCurrent)*PriceFl;
        String sSum = String.format("%.0f", Sum);

        SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(sSum);
        ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, sSum.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        Total.setText("Необходимо "+ssb+" руб.");

}
```

Выводит полностью всю строку одним цветом по умолчанию.
Если же меняю на

```
Total.setText(ssb);
```

то, соответственно, выводится только цена и выводится как надо, красным цветом. Тестирую на устройстве с Android 4.2.2. Как правильно произвести конкатенацию результата со строкой?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `append`

```
private fun stylizationTextInfo(textView: TextView) {
    val result = SpannableStringBuilder()
    val ssb = SpannableStringBuilder("1000")
    val txtNeed = SpannableStringBuilder("Необходимо ")
    val txtMoney = SpannableStringBuilder(" руб.")

    ssb.setSpan(ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, ssb.length, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    result.append(txtNeed).append(ssb).append(txtMoney)
    textView.text = result
}
```

**java:**

```
private void stylizationTextInfo(TextView textView) {
    SpannableStringBuilder result = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder("1000");
    SpannableStringBuilder txtNeed = new SpannableStringBuilder("Необходимо ");
    SpannableStringBuilder txtMoney = new SpannableStringBuilder(" руб.");

    ssb.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, ssb.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    result.append(txtNeed).append(ssb).append(txtMoney);
    textView.setText(result);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, так получилось. Спасибо!